# One global try{} catch{} for all PDO queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, error-handling, try-catch

I rarely use unique error messages for database queries on fail

I often use short standard messages like "database error/fail. please contact webmaster" or something like that. Or make it email me automatically

I'm looking for a way to set try{} and catch{} for ALL queries, once globally, in PDO. So I don't have to write the same over and over

Is that possible? Perhaps wrap it up in a little class?

Comment: "Perhaps wrap it up in a little class?" You answered your own question.

Comment: Ok, well I don' know much about classes ;) Was hoping for a little help

Comment: Then you could also just do it with a function either using a global variable for the connection or passing the connection in as a parameter.

Comment: Ah yes, the connection is already made "global" with this: class DBi {
    public static $conn;
}

Comment: @mowgli did my post answer your question? let me know

Comment: No really, sorry. I wanted to avoid setting try{} catch{} for each little query

Comment: @mowgli you probably did not understand it, in the example below, there is only one `try/catch` for all queries, the other option could be don't catch it just set error mode to the connection attribute so that all instance will throw errors

Answer (score 0):

In a well design application you would write using a design pattern . For example you can achieve this using MVC approach:

**Model**

```
class Students {

    private pdo;

    function __construct($pdo){
    //do something
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    function get_all_students(){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Students");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        return $result;
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
class StudentsController{

    function GetStudentAction(){
        //here you create an instance of that model
        $students_model = new Students();
        $students = $students_model->get_all_students();
        return $students;
    }

}
```

**usage**

```
<?php
include 'Students.php';
include 'StudentsController.php';

try {
     $students = new StudentController();
     $all_students = $students->GetStudentAction();

    //then you have more other models 
    //for example:
     $professors = new ProfessorsController();
     $math_professors = $professors->GetMathProfessorsAction();
}
catch( PDOException $Exception ) {
    //do something with the Exception
    echo( $Exception->getMessage( ) , $Exception->getCode( ) );
}

?>
```

Comment: Isn't this actually EXTENDING the native PDO unnecessarily? And you still set try / catch for the query

Comment: What does ectending mean

Comment: I see absolutely no reason for all of this. And how does this target my question?

Comment: Sometimes you are not ready for certain concept please feel free to revisit this answer in the future

Comment: Ok, but please read my question again, then look at your answer ;)

Comment: This is a single try catch where you include your models, i dont see what part of this you dont understand. If you arent going to try please dont bother.